# Creating a PDF viewer for Silverlight, without external plugin

Tags: image, silverlight, pdf, mvvm, png

I'm trying to implement / use PDF viewer for Silverlight 5 in the browser.
Googling the subject produced some interesting results but most of them are based
on having an external PDF viewer such as Acrobat. I want to achieve this without having the user installing software.

I've understood that it can be done by converting the PDF to PNG and displaying the PNG file.

I'm trying to show a png file. I've succeeded using the simple tool

I'm using MVVM and is new to Silverlight.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do I Implement this? Is there an example somewhere I can learn from?